# Добавление строки в таблицу БД

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

Суть проблемы в исключении

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`postschema`.`post`, CONSTRAINT `FK3498A06BAB423F` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`))

Пишу блог, сущности описал с помощью Hibernate, соединение с базой JDBC.
Пример кода.
Сущности:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column (name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column (name = "summary", nullable = false)
    private String summary;

    @Column (name = "body", nullable = false)
    private String body;
    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Post(String title, String summary, String body, Category category) {

        this.title = title;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.body = body;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Post() {

    }
    public Post(ResultSet resultSet, Category category){
        try {
            this.id = resultSet.getInt("id");
            this.body = resultSet.getString("body");
            this.summary = resultSet.getString("summary");
            this.title = resultSet.getString("title");
            this.category = category;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private String categoryName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Post> posts;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

    public void setPosts(List<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    public Category() {

    }
}
```

Класс подключения к БД и получения SQL запросов

```
public class QueryProperties {

    Properties queries;

    private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/postschema";
    private final String USERNAME = "root";
    private final String PASSWORD = "******";

    public QueryProperties() {
       loadProperties();
    }

    public Connection getConnectionDB()
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Driver driver = new FabricMySQLDriver();
            DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Driver not found!");        }

    return connection;
    }

    public String getQuery (String name){
        System.out.println("Get query " + name);
        if (queries == null)
            loadProperties();
            String q = queries.getProperty(name);
            System.out.println(q);
            return q;

    }

    private void loadProperties(){
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/queries.properties");
            queries = new Properties();
            queries.load(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ДАО и его реализация(Одного метода)

```
public interface AbstractDao <T> {

    public T create(T entity);
    public void delete(T entity);
    public T edit(T entity);
    public T getById(Integer id);
    public List<T> getAll();

}

public abstract class AbstractDaoImpl<T> implements AbstractDao<T> {

        QueryProperties queryProperties = new QueryProperties();

    public T create(T entity) {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            connection = queryProperties.getConnectionDB();
            String querys = getCreateQuery();
            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(querys, Statement.NO_GENERATED_KEYS);
            fillCreateStatement(pstmt, entity);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

            resultSet = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (resultSet.next()){
                Integer generatedId = resultSet.getInt(1);
                return getById(generatedId);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null)  try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
            if (pstmt != null)      try { pstmt.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
            if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        }


        return null;
    }
}


public class PostDao extends AbstractDaoImpl<Post> {

    @Override
    public void fillCreateStatement(PreparedStatement pstmt, Post entity) {
        try {
            pstmt.setString(1, entity.getBody());
            pstmt.setString(2, entity.getSummary());
            pstmt.setString(3, entity.getTitle());
            pstmt.setLong(4, entity.getCategory().getId());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Main класс (для проверки работы)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PostDao postDao = new PostDao();
        Post post = new Post();
        Category category = new Category();
        category.setCategoryName("usdgliuidfl");
        post.setTitle("jgsdhjksddlgh");
        post.setSummary("skdjhgdgsd");
        post.setBody("jhgsdajkldgh");
        post.setCategory(category);
        postDao.create(post);
        System.out.println("Added!");
    }
}
```

Конфигурационный файл Hibernate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/postschema</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">peroser12</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping class="model.Category"/>
        <mapping class="model.User"/>
        <mapping class="model.Post"/>
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

На английский ресурсах искал решения, единственное что понял, что связанно с конфликтом ключей. 
Прошу вашей помощи, уважаемые коллеги.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно поняли как нужно использовать ORM (в данном случае Hibernate). Если вы работаете через ORM, и вам нужно поместить объект в базу данных, то не нужно писать SQL и обращаться к JDBC. Вам нужно инициализировать `SessionFactory`, с вашим `DataSource`, получить оттуда сессию и сделать persist(). Если Entity корректно описаны, Hibernate сделает остальную работу за вас.

В вашем примере, исключение говорит о том, что имея два объекта, связанных через Foreign Key (Post ссылается на Category), вы пытаетесь вставить Post в базу данных первым. Естественно получаете исключение, потому что снчала нужно вставить туда Category, получить его автоикрементированный ID. А уже потом вставлять Post.

В случае использования Hibernate использовать foreign Key, вообще, не обязательно. Он сам может удалить связанные объекты. Но можно оставить его для подстраховки, или если выработатете с БД не только через Hibernate (скрипты, хранимые процедуры).

Comment: Не совсем могу понять как работает метод persist(). Просто напросто создать класс- модель, указать его поля и указать её как параметр данного метода?

Comment: @Дмитрий да, вся суть ORM - заставить забыть о базе данных и начать работать с объектами вместо БД

Comment: @Etki Данным способом пробовал. Persist не проходит. Только транзакциями.

Comment: @Дмитрий транзакции не противоречат hibernate и orm

Comment: @Дмитрий Если у вас трудности с использованием Hibernate, создайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос и приведите ваш код. В этом вопросе тема уже раскрыта.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.